# How smart is the OS about scheduling blocked processes?

Tags: concurrency, scheduling, process

Let's consider two processes P1 and P2 that are blocked because of semaphores S1 and S2.
When a third process comes and unblocks semaphore S2, will the operating system know that it should schedule P2 to run, or it will schedule randomly a process, S1 for example which is not optimal. It will see again that S1 is blocked and try to schedule something else

Comment: I believe it's totally dependent of OS that you use. There is some info about process scheduling in different OS: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheduling_(computing)#Operating_system_scheduler_implementations